# Android Studio Layout Preview

Tags: android, android-studio, layout

I am new to Android UI Development.
I had to create a layout (relative layout which contains a view pager, a linear layout which holds multiple buttons and textviews).
I am able to see that when I install the APK I build on the device, the layout is rendered as expected.
But the preview/design screens in Android Studio just show only a couple of the UI elements while everything else is missing.
I wanted to make multiple iterations of changes and view the designs.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes that are made at run time are not visible in the layout designer. That is why widgets like ViewPager, ListView ,... are blank in the designer. Their adapters are populated and set at run time. Also layouts can be constructed and added programatically.